# Responsive website not able to have 100% width in smaller screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When viewing http://rayku.com on a mobile device (anything with iPhone 5 resolution or smaller), there is a horizontal scroll bar - how can I maximize the content width so that there is no horizontal scroll bar? http://d.pr/i/epmI

There is no min-width anywhere in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll is due to the left margin of the `button` inside the video container `.myVideoCont`.

If you need to center align the button over the video, then use
`left:50%;   transform: translateX(-50%);`. and avoid left margin.

Comment: may I know the reason for the down vote please?

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this CSS to target screens below a tablet size, decrease the max-device-width pixels to only target smaller devices:



@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

    #mainContainer {
        max-width: 90%; //also try "width: 90%" 
    }   
}


If this doesn't work try setting the width to 80% and keep decreasing until it fits.
```